# The Zariski topology on $\mathbb{K}^n $ is Noetherian.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, zariski-topology

A topological space is Noetherian if there are no infinite descending chains of closed sets.
Show that the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{K}^n $ is Noetherian.

I know and understand what is topological space, and Zariski topology.

The Zariski topology on any field $\mathbb{K}^n$ has as closed sets $Z(I)$, where $I \subseteq R = \mathbb{K}[x_1 ,... , x_n]$ an ideal with property $Z(0)= \mathbb{K}^n $ and $Z(1)= \emptyset $.

How I should prove it? Thank you so much !

Comment: Descending chain of closed sets translates to ascending chain of ideals in $R$...

Comment: @redwhisker Ok... but how can I prove it? I tried but I don't have any idea... please! and thank you

Comment: Have a look at the answer below. The idea is that if $Z_1\supseteq Z_2$ are (closed) subsets, then you can take their vanishing ideals to get a reverse containment: $I(Z_1)\subseteq I(Z_2)$ simply because anything that vanishes on $Z_1$ necessarily vanishes on $Z_2$. So, a descending chain "translates" to an ascending chain of ideals which stabilizes because $R$ is Noetherian (and equal ideals have equal vanishing sets).

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ and $J$ are ideal on $R:=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and $I<J$, then $V(J)\subset V(I)$, and viceversa. Then descending chain of closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$ are equivalent to an ascending chain of ideals in the ring $R$. But Hilbert's basis theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem) tells us that $R$ is Noetherian. It means that any ascending chain of ideals in $R$ is finite, so any descending chain of closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is also finite.

A very naive and easy way to see that $I<J$ implies that $V(J)\subset V(I)$ is that $I$ is generated with fewer equations than $J$, then the set of point vanishing in the generators of $I$ is bigger than the set of points whose vanish in all the generators of $J$.

Comment: But do we  not need that thr descending chain closed set in $\mathbb{A}^n$ stabilizes?

Comment: It stabilizes because the ascending chain in $R$ stabilizes...

Comment: Starting from $V(J) \subseteq V(I)$ it is not necessary that $I \subseteq J$ but in this case $V(J) = V(I + J)$, so we can reduce to the case where the ideals are in an ascending chain.